# Subtle permissions change when dumping a postgres database from Linux to Windows using a pipe

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I copy a postgresql database from Linux to Windows with this command

> pg_dump -C -h toolbox.mydomain.com -U postgres auth | psql -h
>   localhost -U postgres auth

When I have the datasource use the Windows version of Postgresql and I do a Hibernate merge on the child entity (owning side) of a one to many relationship I get a permissions error from Postgresql:

```
2012-06-21 14:39:42 MDT ERROR:  permission denied for schema stage at character 20
2012-06-21 14:39:42 MDT QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "stage"."job" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x
2012-06-21 14:39:42 MDT STATEMENT:  insert into stage.file (job_id, name) values ($1, $2) RETURNING *
```

If I point the datasource to the Postgres database on the Linux server there is no problem.  The credentials are the same for the two datasources and the schemas on the two Postgresql instances have the same permissions as far as I can tell.

What am I missing?  Is there some subtle problem with dumping a database over a pipe like this?  Maybe a UNIX versus Windows issue?

Thanks for any suggesions.

Answer (score 2):

Roles (users and groups) are global objects in PostgreSQL. `pg_dump` won't necessarily create roles for you. I note that you're doing the restore side without `-1` so it won't fail if there is an error. Quite likely what is happening is that some expected `GRANT` statements are failing but you're not noticing the errors.

Examine the server logs from the time of the restore, or re-run it with `ON_ERROR_STOP=1 psql -1 ....` to ensure it fails if anything goes wrong.

Personally I prefer to use `pg_dump -Fc` and `pg_restore` as they give me a lot more control over restore behaviour, error handling, etc.

To dump global objects like roles use `pg_dumpall --globals-only` .